# Orientdb fetch plan returning ID instead of record

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, sails-orientdb

I am querying a class from the Sails-orientdb adapter for Sailjs. I expect to see last_comment field expanded but it just gives me back the ID. In orientdb studio the same SQL below shows the last_comment expanded

```
    Questions.query("select * from Questions fetchplan last_comment:0 order by createdAt desc", function (err, retrievedQuestions) {
        if (err) res.send(500,"Error")
        res.send(200, retrievedQuestions);
    });
```

How can I get the resultset to return expanded?

Orientdb v2.0.12

Answer (score 1):

can you try with level:1

```
Questions.query("select * from Questions fetchplan last_comment:1 order by createdAt desc", function (err, retrievedQuestions) {
        if (err) res.send(500,"Error")
        res.send(200, retrievedQuestions);
    });
```

Comment: Doesnt make a difference. The following gets returned last_comment: '#19:2'. Its the same as trying with level:0

Comment: Yes it is direct link. It shows up in the oriented studio expanded

Comment: ok let me check in sails-orientdb.
Which version are you using?

Comment: Version 10.55 with the orientjs libs